# Webkit on Windows Mobile

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, webkit, windows-ce

I wish to embed webkit in a windows mobile application. The goal is to allow it to run web apps. I've tried the Qt version, but only webkit is required and not the rest of the functionality Qt has.

Comment: so, what's your question ? :)

Comment: How do I build webkit on wince?

Answer (score 2):

You can build WebKit for WinCE out of trunk in the meantime.
See http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WinCE.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.torchmobile.com/ had a ported webkit browser called IRIS.

Apparently they have recently been swallowed by RIM.

Answer (score 1):

We posted the alpha free download version
www.zetakey.com/download.html

with or without FLASH support available